# How to iterate through a list using index

Tags: python, list, loops

I am making a function that counts from 0 to a certain number input I tried to make it using print and that worked but the output needs to be a return value so I tried making a list then iterating through it using a for loop and returning each value of the list back using the index of the list but that didn't work it only returns the last value of the list I also want the returned value to be a string, not a list.

this is my code

```
nums = []
def numbers_range(number):
  for i in range(number+1):
    numz = nums.append(i)
  for g in range(len(nums)):
   numb = nums[g]
  return numb

print(numbers_range(5))
```

result 5
the result i want 0 1 2 3 4 5
please help

Comment: In your case, you're just creating a single variable `numz` and a single variable `numb`.  You're not creating a list.  `list.append` does not return anything, so `numz` will never have a value.  ALL YOU NEED in your loop is `return list(range(number+1))`.

Comment: that will create a list and thats not exactly what I need I need the values inside the list to be returned as a string

Comment: @EltayibYousif fine, then `return " ".join(range(number + 1))`.

Comment: Let me provide a bit of philosophy.  In general, in a case like this, it's most useful to have the function return the basic data (that is, a list of integers) and allow the CALLER to decide what to do with it.  You only need a string if you are going to print it, and a function like this should not need to know that.  Just return the list, and do the `join` operation when you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop containing variable 'g' is putting values 1 over next in same variable numb.
Basically each value in numb is being overridden by new value from list.

Do this instead.

```
def numbers_range(number):
  nums = []
  for i in range(number+1):
    nums.append(i)
  
  ans = "".join([str(no) for no in nums])
  return ans

print(numbers_range(5))
```

Here in code,

1. We are creating a new list called **nums**.
2. Then we are traversing from 0 to the number and appending each value into the list.
3. Finally returning the list converted to string.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the OP wants, and is a really overly complicated way of just doing `list(range(5 + 1))`

Comment: I want to code to return the numbers as a string, not in a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, There is always another way for any question :)

Comment: @EltayibYousif apparently, you do not

Comment: And doing `ans+= str(no) ` in a loop is an anti-pattern. You really should use `.join`

Comment: Yes, there were option like join function or using map function. But again I choosed the basic one so he'd at least understand what we are doing!

Comment: @ShivamPapat It's not **an issue of basic or advanced**. That is a *bad algorithm*, a classic antipattern that should be avoided. Linters will explicitly tell you *not* to do that. That is a quadratic time algorithm. Don't use it. EDIT: at least, you answer does what the OP purports to want, though

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes agree.  Updated the code. (Everytime a new string will be created and data will be copied that's why concatenation isn't good).

Comment: So, one simlpe way to make this more reasonable is just `nums.append(str(i))` and then `return " ".join(nums)`

Comment: Oh yes, correct

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(number+1):
    numz = nums.append(i)

for g in range(len(nums)):
    numb = nums[g]
```

What you're doing here is iterating through a list and assign the items to variable one by one. In each turn the variable is overwritten.
So when the loop terminates only the value assigned is final value in the list.

In case you need to `return` a sequence of numbers you can implement your code with `eval` function. But the returning values are strings, not integers. As you're just returning them, it won't be an issue.

```
def numbers_range(number):
    x =0
    s =''
    while x<=number:
# if you don't need a new line replace '\n' with a space ' ' .
         s =(s+str(x)+"\n")
         x =x+1
    numb = eval("print(s)")
    return numb
```

when using the function,

```
print(numbers_range(5))
```

output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: a creative and nice solution it worked for me but you just need to replace (n) in the while loop and put the argument variable (number). Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

one solution is

```
def numbers_range(number):
            ans = [str(i) for i in range(number+1)]
            return " ".join(ans)
                
print(numbers_range(5))
```

another solution is

```
def numbers_range(number):
    ans = []
    for i in range(number+1):
        ans.append(str(i))
    return " ".join(ans)
    


print(numbers_range(5))
```

Comment: `numbers_range` is completely pointless

Comment: @EltayibYousif this is not doing what you repeatedly said you wanted to do, e.g. returning a string. You could have just done `for i in range(5 + 1): print(i, end=" ")`

Comment: You are simply redoing lot of work

Answer (score -3):

So I think the issue is in your use of `range()`. In my experience, `range()` needs to be formatted like `range(min, max)` whereas you are formatting it like `range(min)`.

I think what you want would come from this code:

```
nums = []
def numbers_range(number):
  for i in range(0, number+1):
    numz = nums.append(i)
  for g in range(0, len(nums)):
   numb = nums[g]
  return numb

print(numbers_range(5))
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: NO this is still wrong, Please go through your inner for loop. There lies the error

Comment: No, `range(n)` is equivalent to `range(0, n)` this is definitely not the issue